# Why does the newly created EC2 instance does not send resource signal to AWS Cloud Formation after I replace the AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a WordPress AWS Cloud formation stack that runs some custom scripts and module on server side. The current Cloud formation template attached AMI does not have those custom scripts and modules in it. So I was replacing the CFN AMI with my newly created AMI with same configuration only additional scripts and modules installed in it.

What is happening is once I change the old AMI Id with my new AMI ID and update the stack the instance is getting created but the newly created instance is it not sending the resource signal to CFN and AWS CFN is rolling it back to old AMI. How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: The signal is typically something sent manually via the user data script. Have you modified the user data script? Does your new AMI have `cfn-signal` installed and in the same path as the old AMI?

Comment: Also, on stack update you can set the option to not rollback on failure. that will leave the bad instances up so that you can inspect the cloud-init logs.

Comment: @jordanm so the new AMI is a replica of old AMI only it has 2 cron jobs installed in it thats it and it already has cfn-signal

Comment: Then you will need to inspect the cloud-init logs to see why cfn-signal is either failing or not getting executed.